# Amortized Analysis - Right approach?

Tags: algorithm

Studying for an exam and stumbled upon this exercise. I'm having trouble solving it with all three methods. Here's the text:

> Suppose we are maintaining a data structure under a series of n operations.
> Let f(k) denote the actual running time of the kth
> operation. For each of the following functions f, determine the
> resulting amortized cost of a single operation. (For practice, try all
> of the methods described in this note.)
>
> (a) f(k) is the largest integer i such that 2^i divides k.

source: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/fa2013/notes/14-amortize.pdf

I made a small table to try to get an overview

```
k    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ...
f(k) 0  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3   3   3   3   3   3   4   ...
```

I don't see where the potential method could help here as the operations just get more expensive over time. Banker's Method also doesn't seem to be applicable here for the same reason. So I thought aggregate method would be most suitable.

[image]

is what I came up with for a sequence of n operations, however I can't seem to transform it, which makes me question whether or not it's the right approach.

EDIT: so it looks like I misunderstood the question I think the correct table would look like this:

```
k    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ...
f(k) 0  1  0  2  0  1  0  3  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   4   ...
```

Comment: The table is wrong (for example 2^3 does not divide 11), that makes it trickier

Comment: 8 doesn't divide 11? Maybe it's a semantics problem.. x divides y iff y div x > 0?

Comment: "x divides y" means y/x is an integer

Comment: or do they mean divides evenly? oh man that makes it easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick answer in case anybody googles this

using the banker's method you can 'save' a constant amount of credits (in this case 2 per operation would work) and easily cover the costs of the more expensive ones down the line.

```
k    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ...
f(k) 0  1  0  2  0  1  0  3  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   4   ...
cr   2  3  5  5  7  8  10 9  11 12  14  15  17  18  20  18  ...
```